# Get penultimate versions of packages with pipenv

Tags: python, pip, package, pipenv

At the moment I am freezing packages with pipenv to specific versions in my `Pipfile` file, for instance:

```
[packages]
django = {version = "==3.0.8"}
gunicorn = {version = "==20.0.4"}
django-storages = {version = "==1.9.1"}
```

Is there a syntax in pipenv to set the penultimate versions?

```
[packages]
django = {version = "==3.0.7"}
gunicorn = {version = "==20.0.3"}
django-storages = {version = "==1.9.0"}
```